# Show paypal payment on checkout page

Tags: magento, paypal

I am working with magento and I wanted to know is there any way to show paypal payment method on one page checkout?

Answer (score 0):

Magento  is provide paypal  on his  system
.GOTo `admin>System>Configuration>Sales>Payment method` tab
.Her you have find paypal stetting 
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/3_-_store_setup_and_management/payment/paypal_standard_payments_setup_with_ipn

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/setting-up-paypal-payments-standard-for-magento-community

Comment: thanks for answer.                                                            I Already configured Paypal, but i want to add paypal button with other payment method in checkout page.

Comment: Please put more details on question

Comment: what dont you understand? The paypal button is shown in my cart page. And i wanted to know if i can put that button in checkout page with other payment methods?

Answer (score 0):

- Copy core file `app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Config.php` to local directory: `app/code/local/Mage/Paypal/Model/Config.php`
- In `Config.php` file, look for variable `$_supportedCurrencyCodes`
- It will be displayed as follows:

  ```
  protected $_supportedCurrencyCodes = array('AUD', 'CAD', 'CZK', 'DKK', 'EUR', 'HKD', 'HUF', 'ILS', 'JPY', 'MXN',
      'NOK', 'NZD', 'PLN', 'GBP', 'SGD', 'SEK', 'CHF', 'USD', 'TWD', 'THB');
  ```
- Add your currency in the array. For example, I have added `NPR` currency below:

  ```
  protected $_supportedCurrencyCodes = array('AUD', 'CAD', 'CZK', 'DKK', 'EUR', 'HKD', 'HUF', 'ILS', 'JPY', 'MXN',
  'NOK', 'NZD', 'PLN', 'GBP', 'SGD', 'SEK', 'CHF', 'USD', 'TWD', 'THB', 'NPR');
  ```
- Now, paypal payment option should be displayed in your checkout page.